# Enable Add-In Button if One Feature is Selected from Specific Layer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, vb.net, visual-studio, toolbar

I am trying to enable an add-in button on my toolbar if only one feature is selected from a specifc Layer. For example, when ArMap loads, the button should be disabled. If the user selects one feature from the AJ_RecommendedImprovementsPoints layer, then the button enables. Here's what I have, but it's not working at all. suggestions??

```js
Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()
    'Get Transportation Improvement Projects
    Dim pFeatLyr As IFeatureLayer
    pFeatLyr = GetLayerByTOC("RV_ImprovementPoints")
    'Enable Button
    If GetFeatSelCount(pFeatLyr) = 1 Then
        Me.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub


Public Function GetFeatSelCount(ByVal pFeatLyr As IFeatureLayer) As Long
    'Returns # of selected featurues of feature layer as long integer
    'Initialize the required variables
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    pMxDoc = My.ArcMap.Document
    Dim pMap As IMap
    pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
    Dim pFeatSel As IFeatureSelection
    pFeatSel = pFeatLyr
    Dim pFeatSelectionSet As ISelectionSet
    pFeatSelectionSet = pFeatSel.SelectionSet
    GetFeatSelCount = pFeatSelectionSet.Count
End Function


Public Function GetLayerByTOC(ByVal lyrName As String) As IFeatureLayer
    'This function finds a feature layer based on its TOC Name
    Try
        'Initialize the required variables
        Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
        pMxDoc = My.ArcMap.Document
        Dim pMap As IMap
        pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
        Dim lyrCntr As Integer
        Dim pFeatLyr As IFeatureLayer
        For lyrCntr = 0 To pMap.LayerCount - 1
            'Ensure that the layer is valid
            If pMap.Layer(lyrCntr).Valid = True Then
                'Ensure that the layer is a feature layer
                If TypeOf pMap.Layer(lyrCntr) Is IFeatureLayer Then
                    pFeatLyr = pMap.Layer(lyrCntr)
                    If UCase(pMap.Layer(lyrCntr).Name) = UCase(lyrName) Then
                        GetLayerByTOC = pFeatLyr
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next lyrCntr
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Layer not found. Show a message
        MsgBox("Layer " & lyrName & " not found !", vbCritical, "Error")
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a function that returns the selection set count property on your layer.  If the count is >0 than you can enable your button.

[ISelectionSet.Count Property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Count_Property/002500000807000000/)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking for a selection directly in the button's `OnUpdate` routine, which runs very frequently, I would write an extension that uses event handlers to respond to selection events and caches the selection state of your layer, and then in the `OnUpdate` routine check the extension's cached state.

Of course this is probably overkill if there is only one button/command to be updated, but it would be good practice. See this sample ([SelectionExtension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000003w2000000.htm)) for an example as well as [Add-in coding patterns](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000zz000000) for best practices.